# Error in roc.default(pima_01$diabetic, candidate1$fitted.values) : 'response' must have two levels

Tags: r

```
Error in roc.default(pima_01$diabetic, candidate1$fitted.values) : 
  'response' must have two levels
```

Comment: As per the error, your response variable (`pima_01$diabetic`, I assume) does not have any variation.

Comment: Can you please clarify in what context this error occurred? What did you try to do and what data are you using? (a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or even the `head()` and/or `str()` of the data would be useful)